# How to export a list of df to separate csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to export a list of pandas dataframes to indivudal csv files.

I have currently got this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"a":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], "b":[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ["a","b"])
df = np.array_split(df, 3)
```

I have tried:

```
for i in df:
    i.to_csv((r'df.csv'))
```

However this doesn't ouput all the sub df, only the last one.

How do I get this to output all the df, with the outputted csv having the names df1.csv, df2.csv, and df3.csv?

Comment: All the answers worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're writing each data frame to the same file, `'df.csv'`. In your `for` loop, you can specify both the dataframes to save and the files to save them to with `zip()`.

```py
>>> for i, outfile in zip(df, ["df1.csv", "df2.csv", "df3.csv"]):
...     i.to_csv(outfile)
```

You can do this particular task a number of ways. Here's a loop with `enumerate()` so you don't have to write the whole list of filenames.

```py
>>> for j, frame in enumerate(df):
...     frame.to_csv(f"df{j+1}.csv")
```

Comment: OP's use of a raw string was unnecessary. But it is interesting to note that, if OP does want a raw string, formatted raw strings do exist in Python. You can do fr"df{j}.csv" One of those niche but super cool Python features.

Answer (score 0):

It did output all three. It's just that the second one overwrote the first, and likewise with the last one. You have to write them out to three separate filenames.

To achieve this, we need to modify the string based on where we are in the loop. The easiest way to do this is with a counter on the loop. Since the variable 'i' is normally reserved for such counters, I'm going to rename your dummy variable to _df. Don't get confused by it. To get a counter in the loop, we use enumerate.

```
for i, _df in enumerate(df):
    print(i)
    filename = 'df' + str(i) + '.csv'
    _df.to_csv(filename) # I think the extra parenthesis are unecessary?
```

edit: Just to note the advantage of this over the suggestion of specifying all the filenames in a list is that you don't need to know the length of the list in advance. Also helpful if you do know the length, but it is big. If it's 3 and you know it's 3 and that won't change, then you can specify the filenames as suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can use floor division on the index then use a groupby to create your individual frames.

```
for data, group in df.groupby(df.index // 3):
    group.to_csv(f"df{data+1}.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is getting replace in same file with each iterations.

Try :

```
for i, value in enumerate(df):
    value.to_csv('/path/to/folder/df'+str(i)+'.csv')
```